# Excel VBA Images

Tags: excel, vba

I have about ten images, however I will want to pick four or five based on user's selection from a combobox. However, I  would like to know how to be sure that the image picked matches ComboBox's Label. And is it okay to keep the images on an excel sheet? That is why I do not want the below style. Is it possible to adjust the size of image?

```
Sub update_data()
   Sheet1.Cells(2, 2) = Sheet1.ComboBox1.Value
   Sheet1.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(VBAProject.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\pics\" &      Sheet1.ComboBox1.Value & ".jpg")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use if then selection.

For example

```
If range("a1") = "Your Value" Then 
Range("A1").select 
Activesheet.Pictures.insert and your file path.
```